# How to handle events in skia?

Tags: events, event-handling, click, skia

I am intending to use skia for an app. How to handle events like web input box click, wheel events etc in Skia ? What are the possible events in skia?  How to handle events in skia?

Comment: Skia is a graphics library, not a UI library. Skia does not know about web input boxes or mouse wheels.

Answer (score 0):

React Graphics Library Built on Skia - https://github.com/bridgedxyz/nothing

It'll have Similar api such like Konva React, but built on skia instead. - better performance